# GORM: how to set datatype of a value in a Map

Tags: grails, dictionary, grails-orm

in my domain object i have a map:

```
Map<String, String> stuff
```

GORM automatically creates a table where the key and the value are **varchar(255)**.

i need the value to be **LongText** instead. How do i do this thing?

Also, is there a workaround for this that doesnt involve using the hibernate config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid only via [Hibernate XML config](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html#15.1%20Using%20Hibernate%20XML%20Mapping%20Files) and [specifying a `key` mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-mapping) for the `stuff`.

Comment: See the answer from Carlos Daniel Gadea Om. It actually does work for `Map<String, String>`

Answer (score 3):

I think you can declare this setting in the mapping closure of your Domain class.

Constraint for a String field so that its MySQL column type is TEXT:

```
static mapping = {
   myTextField type: 'text'
}
```

Maybe this can help you out: Grails Guide [(5.5.2.1 Table and Column Names)](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/single.html#5.5.2%20Custom%20ORM%20Mapping)

Comment: this would work if 'stuff' was a scalar type, but it doesnt work for a Map

Comment: It actually does work for `Map<String, String>`. Key will always be varchar(255), but value is longtext in MySQL and longvarchar in H2 and HSQLDB.

Comment: Tested in Grails 1.3.7, 2.0.0 and 2.1.1. From schema export: `create table foo_baz (baz bigint, baz_idx varchar(255), baz_elt longvarchar not null);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more control of how the database is generated/updated then it is better to use a database migration then letting Hibernate manage it. We use Liquibase which is very easy to use and flexible and there is already a [Grails plug in](http://www.grails.org/plugin/liquibase) for it. Also, if I am not mistaken database migrations are going to be integrated in Grails core for version 1.4 so you will be able to use schema migrations without having to install any plug in.